# If we could remove all auto-antibodies would the auto-immune disease get cured?

Tags: autoimmune-disease, antibodies

Some people tell me that yes, by eliminating all auto-antibodies the auto-immune disorder would cease (and maybe some old-cell/toxins removal abilities as well).

Others say that auto-antibodies are just correlated with auto-immune activity, but that their removal does not affect the auto-immune disease, and the underlying mechanism is still not known, but is clearly not dependent on the concentration of auto-antibodies.

Is there a correct answer to this question?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Specifically, who are "some people" and "others?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there actually is a correct answer to this: not every autoimmune disease is antibody driven. Take coeliac disease: antibodies are just an epiphenomenon of the immune process, which is actually cell-mediated ([Medscape](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/932104-overview#a5)). Thinking about the pathophysiology of certain autoimmune diseases should help in understanding this: something goes wrong in the antigen presenting cell - T cell interaction and a "self" component gets recognized as potentially harmful. T cells start attacking it, B cell start producing antibodies against it. In certain diseases, it's the antibodies that do the harm. In others, it's the cells.
So, by eliminating all autoantibodies you most certainly won't eradicate all autoimmune disease. Probably some (such as Myasthenia gravis, which can be treated with [plasmapheresis](https://www.medscape.com/answers/1171206-92688/what-is-the-role-of-plasmapheresis-in-the-treatment-of-myasthenia-gravis-mg)), but not all.

Hope this helped, i tried using a simple language but since English is not my mothertongue I maybe overdid it.